# Using get_template_part to retrieve a template file based on current post type

Tags: get-template-part

I'm trying to use get_template_part to retrieve a template file based on the current post type (slug) the user is in. The template file just includes an image that is used specific to specific post types.

```
<?php get_template_part('parts/get_post_type( $post )') ?><p id="t3-splash-title"><?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) ); echo $post_type->labels->singular_name ; ?></p>
```

The above doesn't blow up the page, but nothing seems to get output. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [built in support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) for that, kind of. While I don't see anything wrong with your code, try naming your files on the form `archive-mytype.php`, `content-mytype.php` etc. and then call `get_template_part` like this:

```
<!--  This will result in including parts/content-mytype.php -->
<?php get_template_part('parts/content', get_post_type( $post )); ?>
<p id="t3-splash-title"><?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) ); echo $post_type->labels->singular_name ; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is partly just bad PHP and partly a misunderstanding of `get_template_part`.

You are literally asking for a file named "parts/get_post_type( $post )". Closer to right would be...

```
get_template_part('parts/'.get_post_type( $post ));
```

Since [`get_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) returns a `boolean` on failure I'd lean towards something more like this though...

```
$type = get_post_type($post);
if (!empty($post)) {
   get_template_part('parts/'.$type ));
} else {
  // something or nothing; your choice
}
```

Now [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is going to be looking for file names like "parts/-post-type.php". It looks for `{slug}-{$name}`, or parameter1-parameter2, which is probably not what you want. I imagine that your files are actually "parts/post-type.php" so you will need to rethink your naming scheme.

Comment: Taking your suggestion, I've changed up my naming convention to posttype-banner.

This, by itself outputs what I want:
    `<?php get_template_part( 'parts/dentistry-banner', '' ); ?>`

Comment: I got it set now. Thank you for your help!
'<?php get_template_part('parts/banner',$post->post_type); ?>'